# Evaluating boolean expression in C#

Tags: c#, boolean, expression, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have written the code below to evaluate a boolean expression. The expression is coded in the form of objects.

It's one of those moments when I look at the code and think: I'm sure there's a better way to code that, using less boolean variables but can't see the right way to go. Any help? Unit tests have been written and are passing for a variety of inputs.

```
if (tree == null || !tree.IsActive || tree.FilterNodes == null)
{
     return false;
}
var result = false;
foreach (var filter in tree.FilterNodes.Where(a => a.IsActive && a.ConditionNodes != null))
{
     var tempBool = false;
     foreach (var condition in filter.ConditionNodes.Where(a => a.IsActive))
     {
          if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(condition.FieldName) && values.ContainsKey(condition.FieldName))
          {
               var value = values[condition.FieldName];
               if (filter.LogicalOperator == LogicalOperator.Or && ApplyCondition(condition.ConditionOperator, value, condition.FieldValue))
               {
                   tempBool = true;
                   break;
               }
               else if (filter.LogicalOperator == LogicalOperator.And)
               {
                   tempBool = ApplyCondition(condition.ConditionOperator, value, condition.FieldValue);
                   if (!tempBool)
                   {
                        break;
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   tempBool = false;
               }
           }
           else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(condition.FieldName) && filter.LogicalOperator == LogicalOperator.And)
           {
                tempBool = false;
           }
     }
     result = tempBool;
     if (!result)
     {
          break;
     }
}
return result;
```

Comment: I know its a bit late but did you tried the [Shunting yard algorithm](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard-Algorithmus)? I implemented something simillar but instead of objects I evaluate expressions strings. May take a look [here](https://github.com/Genfood/Proviant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set `tempBool = false` first thing in the loop and leave out the `else` and last `else if`:

```
 foreach (var condition in filter.ConditionNodes.Where(a => a.IsActive))
 {
      tempBool = false;
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(condition.FieldName) && values.ContainsKey(condition.FieldName))
      {
           var value = values[condition.FieldName];
           if (filter.LogicalOperator == LogicalOperator.Or && ApplyCondition(condition.ConditionOperator, value, condition.FieldValue))
           {
               tempBool = true;
               break;
           }
           else if (filter.LogicalOperator == LogicalOperator.And)
           {
               tempBool = ApplyCondition(condition.ConditionOperator, value, condition.FieldValue);
               if (!tempBool)
               {
                    break;
               }
           }
       }
 }
```

**EDIT**

It gets even simpler:

```
 foreach (var condition in filter.ConditionNodes.Where(a => a.IsActive))
 {
      tempBool = false;
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(condition.FieldName) && values.ContainsKey(condition.FieldName))
      {
           var value = values[condition.FieldName];
           tempBool == ApplyCondition(condition.ConditionOperator, value, condition.FieldValue);

           if ((filter.LogicalOperator == LogicalOperator.And && !tempBool) || (filter.LogicalOperator == LogicalOperator.Or && tempBool))
           {
                break;
           }
       }
 }
```

In the if you need `ApplyCondition` to be true and then set `tempBool` to `true` (also the result of `ApplyCondition`). In the else if you set `tempBool`to the result of `ApplyCondition`. That means you can set `tempBool`to the result of `ApplyCondition`in the first place. Now you just need to decide if you need to break.

Comment: Thanks, but even with that change it still feels complex

Comment: tempbool is set to false before the loop. The only time the value changes it breaks out of the loop. So it's unnecessary to reset it to false at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé you need to change || filter.LogicalOperator == LogicalOperator.Or to || (filter.LogicalOperator == LogicalOperator.Or && tempBool)

Comment: @GregTarr Done!

Answer (score 1):

Taking a more o-o approach, I think your operators need to be defined by classes that inherit from a base class. The base class would have an abstract Evaluate method that your operators implement. You can then use o-o polymorphism to evaluate your operators without worrying about the internal details. Effectively you have the beginnings of a simple interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

A more formal way to code a boolean interpreter is considering a boolean expression as generated by a **formal grammar** and writing a **parser** and an **interpreter** for it. The interpreter could be implemented as an **abstract syntax tree**.

I made an open source library to achieve this, if you want you can take a look on [GitHub](https://github.com/FrancescoBonizzi/Boolli).